# How to plot the shapefile in spatial hadoop

Tags: hadoop, geospatial

i want to plot the shapefile in spatialhadoop, can u explain how to implement

> bin/shadoop plot annual_precipitation.shp ann.png shape:osm width:2000 height:2000 -keep-ratio color:red -vflip -fast -overwrite
>
> Error:
> the general command line syntax is bin/hadoop command[genericoptions][commandoptions]

Comment: waiting for your reply sir

Comment: spatialhadoop.cs.umn.edu/visualization.html this are the link for visualization in spatialhadoop

Answer (score 0):

shadoop gplot test.grid map.png shape:osm width:2000 height:2000 -keep-ratio color:red -vflip -fast -overwrite

This will help you.